# Fortran77 define array with integer variables in first column and string variables in the second

Tags: fortran

How to define array with integer variables in first column and string variables in the second?

For example:
The array `mELF` ideally will have numbers in the first and third columns and strings in the third. I have it working only with integers but now I want to mix different types of variables. Is it possible?

```
  INTEGER, save :: mELF(11000, 11000, 11000)
  DATA mELF/11000*11000*11000*0/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to mix the types of elements of an array in FORTRAN77, or any more recent edition of the language either.  In an array all the elements must be of the same type (and kind).

In modern Fortran, ie 90 and later, you can define a derived type such as;

```
type my_type
  integer :: col1, col3
  character(len=16) :: col2
end type
```

and then declare an array such as

```
type(my_type), dimension(:), allocatable :: my_array
```

and now you have a data structure which you can slice with expressions such as

```
my_array % col2

my_array(1:12) % col1

my_array(2:6) % col2(5:8)
```

and so forth.

Comment: Or in FORTRAN 77 we always have `EQUIVALENCE`.

Comment: Shame on you @VladimirF for even thinking about `EQUIVALENCE` let alone suggesting it !